# Mysql - Ordering by REPLACE() not working as expected

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a table that stores denial codes. All the codes start with a D and are numerical after that.
I have used
select REPLACE(adcode,'D','') as denialCode from approved_denials where adactive is not null
order by denialcode

This still orders like this:
| denialCode |
+------------+
| 1          |
| 10         |
| 11         |
| 14         |
| 16         |
| 17         |
| 18         |
| 19         |
| 2          |
| 20         |
| 21         |
| 23         |
| 25         |
| 3          |
| 30         |
| 4          |
| 5          |
| 6          |

Then i tried:
select adcode from approved_denials where adactive is not null order by REPLACE(adcode,'D','');

This output is:
+--------+
| adcode |
+--------+
| D1     |
| D10    |
| D11    |
| D14    |
| D16    |
| D17    |
| D18    |
| D19    |
| D2     |
| D20    |
| D21    |
| D23    |
| D25    |
| D3     |
| D30    |
| D4     |
| D5     |
| D6     |
+--------+

Is there any way i can strip the 'D' and sort these correctly EG:
D1
D2
D3
D4
D5

Etc...
Thanks.

Comment: ```ORDER BY 0 + REPLACE(adcode,'D','')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type from `replace()` in mysql is varchar, so it is sorted as strings - 12 comes before 2. If you want it sorted numerically, cast it to unsigned-

`cast(replace(adcode, 'D','') as unsigned)`

Comment: I literally just came to edit this. Thank you. I did not know CAST() was a function of mysql until a few minutes ago.